# Causes for bluebird's promisify not working

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

I have an API which implements bluebird.js.
I've got two methods with basically the same flow, one works, the other doesn't. Looking for ideas on what could be wrong.

The flow in words is as follows:

1. Promisify an api.
2. Create an array of promises that utilise the API.
3. use .join.apply to call all of the promises in the array.

Some code:

```
_Promise = require('bluebird');
this.getDataFromSomewhere = function getDataFromSomewhere(array, cb) {
    _Promise.promisifyAll(this);
    let promiseArray = [];
    let keyPrefix = 'some prefix';
    let output = [];

    array.forEach(function(obj, i) {
        promiseArray.push(that.foo(keyPrefix + i, function(err, data) {
            output.push({ data });
        }));
    });

    _Promise.join.apply(null, promiseArray);

    cb(null, output);
});
```

Now, I've got a couple of methods doing so - 'getDataFromSomewhere_1' & 'getDataFromSomewhere_2'.
The thing is that 1 works as expected, but 2 doesn't work synchronously. 
In 1, the cb isn't called until _Promise.join.apply(...) has finished.
In 2, the cb is called immediately afterwards.

I'm trying to figure out what could cause this behaviour. 
Maybe an internal library that is being used makes it async?

How would you debug it?
Is there other tools in bluebird's api that could help?
(I went over a bunch of documentation and couldn't find anything).

Please help :)

Comment: Where are `getDataFromSomewhere_1` and `getDataFromSomewhere_2`?

Comment: The callback should be called only after the promises are fulfilled

Comment: getDataFromSomewhere_1 & _2 are two different methods that use the structure that I've written in the code.
Regarding your second comment, how come for the flow of _1 it works fine and for the flow of _2 it doesn't?

Comment: I really have to see more code to answer that. Can you create a sample working code which could demonstrate the actual problem?

Comment: I wish I could. 
It's a bit complex. 
Each one of the methods uses different 'sub API'. 
I think that the problem might lie there, but I'm not even sure how to check it.... seriously, any idea is welcomed :)

Comment: K, the problem is not with the way I use it. 
In getDataFromSomewhere_2 I call an API that doesn't have promises so that's why it doesn't work (I used the inner function i used in _1 in _2 and everything works fine.